# PHP Mail Attachment

Tags: php

I'm having problem with this php mail function.. it works on pdf file i receive the pdf file from mail good and nothing problem but the other file like zip, rar and docx files i receive some text like base64 and not a file its pure text only.. anyone can solve my problem?

This is the code:

```html
<?php 
//define the receiver of the email 
$to = 'youraddress@example.com'; 
//define the subject of the email 
$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip'))); 
//define the body of the message. 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use mail ().  Php mailer or swift mailer are much better

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: Not sure how to be clearer

Comment: @JeffKuletz phpmailer is a email sending library for PHP

Comment: Dragon means you should use a library for attachments, like: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer it is better written than what you have, and it can do a lot more. It's also very simple.

Comment: how to make this?

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;

Comment: i can't understand github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer how to connect that on my hosting? or its work on localhost?

Comment: how to locate the SMTP Info?

Comment: Your email host would provide you with the SMTP credentials, or use a free SMTP such as gmail. Google the info

Comment: I will try the phpmailer its good but I can't get a message like message sent successfully then I got white screen.. any suggestion again if what happen?
this is my code:
if(!$mail->Send()){
echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
}else{
echo "email sent successfully";
}